# How to match an input value against data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to match an input value against a data attribute but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<input value="" data-match="Training">
```

jQuery:

```
var wrd = $('.js-search-input').data('match');
$('.js-search-input').on('keyup keydown paste', function () {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() === wrd) {
        $('.search-demo-text').show();
    }
});
```

Has anyone got any ideas on the best way to match the input value based on the data-* attribute.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ8Sa/1

Comment: Except that keyup is not needed, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - that's what I am not sure about, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ8Sa/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrd` is equal to "Training" in this case.  You then compare the value **in all lowercase** to this string.  Since "Training" is not lowercase, it will never match.

Also, your input doesn't have the class `js-search-input` as the code implies.  Though I assume this is in place in your real code.

Comment: Yeah I updated the fiddle when I noticed that. Much appreciated!